# can i perform operator overloading of more than 2 objects in python?

Tags: python

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x  

    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        return x

p1 = Point(2)
p2 = Point(2)
print("adding", p1 + p2)
output: 4
```

but if i do this,

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x  

    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        return x

p1 = Point(2)  
p2 = Point(2)
p3 = Point(2)
print("adding", p1 + p2 + p3)
```

i get error:

```
print("adding", p1 + p2 + p3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Point'
```

can someone fix my program?

Comment: Have a look at ``__radd__``: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Comment: You could also just `return Point(x)` to keep them `Point`s instead of `int`s - which may or may not be desirable over using `__radd__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `__add__` method is returning an `int`, but it really ought to return a `Point` instance: you're adding two `Point`s together, so someone using that method would expect that the returned result is also a `Point`. But then the sum won't print nicely, unless you also supply `__repr__` &/or `__str__`  methods; I've given simple examples of both below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Point:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x  

    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        return Point(x)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point({})".format(self.x)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)


p1 = Point(1)  
p2 = Point(2)
p3 = Point(4)

print("Points:", repr(p1), repr(p2), repr(p3))
print("adding", p1 + p2)
print("adding", p1 + p2 + p3)
```

**output**

```
Points: Point(1) Point(2) Point(4)
adding 3
adding 7
```

The `__str__` method gets used when you convert an instance to a string, either explicitly, eg `str(p1)`, or when `print()` does it for you. If a class doesn't have a `__str__` method, its `__repr__` method will be used instead, and if it doesn't have one of those, then the default one inherited from the parent object will be used.

"repr" is short for *representation*. The `__repr__` method should return a string that looks like the call you use to create an instance of the class. This is handy in the interactive interpreter, since if you create any Python object in the interpreter without assigning it to a variable its `repr` gets printed. So you can copy & paste the repr of a class instance in the interpreter to create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `__add__` method returns pure integer, not `Point`.
Replace `return x` with `return self` or add a support for int argument in `_add__`